# Why was the Prophet allowed to marry more than four wives, when we can only marry up to four?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, wife, polygamy

The Prophet Mohammad married about 9 women (I am not sure about the number, but please you edit the exact number)

My question is, we as Muslim, if we can be EQUAL with our wives, we can marry up to 4 woman; why the prophet married more then that?
 I heard it's to spread the Islamic religion, is that the only reason or there is something else. I mean, I can say I want to go to a place where Islamic religion doesn't exist and I will marry several women.

My second question how those wives were able to live?
 I mean in the term of money? Or term of protection?  In the term of love or even in the sexual life? (every wife has her own needs).

My third question: the kids that born from those wives were considered as son of the prophets, did they receive some specific treatment or respect?
Didn't they have a role in spreading Islam or the envasions? (okay I know 1-2 or kids but what about the rest?)

Comment: Yes, definitely a duplicate. I don't think this should have been downvoted, though.

Comment: @Daniel I see why it is downvoted, the quality of formulation is poor.